# Problem with syn with ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net, .net-2.0

I have a method which adds investment status by storedprocedure (in this method I check what actual status is and insert it to table)

```
public void AddStatusInvestment(InvestmentData.InvestmentRow Investment, InvestmentData ds, DictionaryData dict)
            {
            SomeMethodWHichUsesStoredProcedureWithActualStatus();
                     var statInw = PhaseStatusHelper.GetStatusesInvestment(Investment, ds);
            }
```

When I check number I don't see any change:

```
var statInw = PhaseStatusHelper.GetStatusesInvestment(Investment, ds);

 public static List<InvestmentData.StatusesInvestmentRow> GetStatusesInvestment(InvestmentData.InvestmentRow Investment, InvestmentData ds)
        {
            List<InvestmentData.StatusesInvestmentRow> Statuses = 
             new List<InvestmentData.StatusesInvestmentRow>();


        Statuses.AddRange(Investment.GetStatusesInvestmentRows());

        return Statuses;
    }
```

Here is code from designer:

```
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
        public StatusesInvestmentRow[] GetStatusesInvestmentRows() {
            if ((this.Table.ChildRelations["FK_Investment_StatusesInvestment"] == null)) {
                return new StatusesInvestmentRow[0];
            }
            else {
                return ((StatusesInvestmentRow[])(base.GetChildRows(this.Table.ChildRelations["FK_Investment_StatusesInvestment"])));
            }
        }
```

StatusesInvestment table:

```
InvestmentId int
EnumStatusesInvestment int
StatusesInvestmentId int PK
```

What can I do to get correct number of statuses

When I launch my application again number of investment statuses is correct

Comment: I think the most important you have to show us is the `SomeMethodWHichUsesStoredProcedureWithActualStatus` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably didn't refresh the dataset after calling the stored procedure.
A dataset holds a local copy of its data and doesn't update automatically.